# filtering pos-tag results based on tag patterns and other tags

Tags: python, spacy

original sentence

key_list= ['techniques from nonlinear analysis and partial differential equations form the basis for these studies .','differential equations are cool.' 'it is not too great of an equation']

```
    Spacy Tagging.
[[['techniques', 'NNS'], ['from', 'IN'], ['nonlinear', 'JJ'], ['analysis', 'NN'], ['and', 'CC'], ['partial', 'JJ'], ['differential', 'JJ'], ['equations', 'NNS'], ['form', 'VBP'], ['the', 'DT'], ['basis', 'NN'], ['for', 'IN'], ['these', 'DT'], ['studies', 'NNS'], ['.', '.']],
[['differential', 'JJ'], ['equations', 'NNS'], ['are', 'VBP'], ['cool', 'JJ'], ['.', '.']], 
[['it', 'PRP'], ['is', 'VBZ'], ['not', 'RB'], ['too', 'RB'], ['great', 'JJ'], ['of', 'IN'], ['an', 'DT'], ['equation', 'NN']]]
```

I am using a wordnet to make things easier, but is there a way i can get the all the nouns of a sentence as well as tag patterns like [RB,RB,JJ] &[JJ,NN]?

```
required output.
[['techniques' ,'nonlinear analysis', 'differential equations', 'basis','studies'],['differential equations'],['not too great','equation']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this if I understand your question correctly

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

text= """techniques from nonlinear analysis and partial
     differential equations form the basis for these studies. 
     Differential equations are cool. It is not too great of an equation"""
doc = nlp(text)

pattern1 = [{"TAG": {"IN": ["NN", "NNS"]}}]
pattern2 = [{"TAG": "RB"},{"TAG": "RB"}, {"TAG": "JJ"}]

matcher.add("matcher", [pattern1, pattern2])

for sent in doc.sents:
    matches = matcher(sent)
    for match_id, start, end in matches:
        print(sent[start:end])
```

Comment: was not familiar with matcher. I wanted to know if i could tell a pattern, that if it startswith['N'] =pattern3?